# Como linkar um arquivo de computador no meu html?

Tags: html, html5

Como faço para linkar uma pasta do meu computador no meu arquivo html? Cada pasta que quero abrir está dentro de uma mesma pasta em que salvei o meu arquivo html.

Vou deixar o print da tela para ajudar a entender. Dentro da pasta pm-projetos estão as pastas pm-projeto001, pm-projeto002 e pm-projeto003; estas são as pastas que quero abrir no meu arquivo html, que tbm está salvo na pasta pm-projetos.

Eu inseri no href do meu arquivo html o caminho das pastas que quero que apareçam na minha lista, porém ao clicar sobre os links eu obtenho a resposta "Cannot GET /Users/Isadora/Documents/DesenvolvimentoWeb/pm-projetos/pm-proj001".
[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>Projetos</title>
 
</head>

<body>
   
    <ul>
        <li class="feito"><a href="C:Users/Isadora/Documents/DesenvolvimentoWeb/pm-projetos/pm-proj001">Projeto 001</a></li>
        <li class="feito"><a href="C:Users/Isadora/Documents/DesenvolvimentoWeb/pm-projetos/pm-proj002">Projeto 002</a></li>
        <li class="feito"><a href="C:Users/Isadora/Documents/DesenvolvimentoWeb/pm-projetos/pm-proj003">Projeto 003</a></li>

    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seu arquivo tá online ou no computador? O que vai chamar os outros pelo link.

Comment: Vou votar pra fechar por falta de clareza. Onde está a página? Local ou online? Está na mesma pasta das pastas que vc quer abrir? Se é local, deveria ter um arquivo no final do link `C:Users/Isadora/Documents/DesenvolvimentoWeb/projeto001/pagina.html` ou vc quer abrir a pasta toda?

Comment: Qual é o propósito do link, vc quer buscar arquivos de que tipo, é um projeto local ou vai para o servidor? De mais detalhes que fica mais fácil para te dar uma resposta precisa.

Comment: O arquivo está no meu computador, dvd e hugocsl . Está na mesma pasta em que quero abrir. Quero abrir cada uma dessas pastas nos links. São pastas com arquivos html e css.

Comment: Então seu problema não está na pergunta. Poderia edita-la e explicar melhor o que está acontecendo ou incluir mais códigos. Quando a gente clica em um link, alguma coisa acontece, pode ser erro, página não encontrada etc... mas alguma coisa acontece, acontece.

Comment: Ao clicar no link deveria abrir a pasta no navegador.

Comment: Se quiser que abra o index, tem que colocar no final do link "index.html" ...

Comment: dvd , mesmo quando eu coloco o index.html no final ele retorna a mesma resposta "Cannot GET /Users/Isadora/Documents/DesenvolvimentoWeb/pm-projetos/pm-proj001/indx.html" .

Comment: Mas pela imagem que vc postou, ainda tem uma pasta "Libraries" que não está no link

Comment: Antes de "Documents"

Comment: Libraries não é uma pasta, é um recurso do Windows 7 que agrupa pastas em Bibliotecas/Libraries. Não correspodente ao caminho canônico, @dvd.

Comment: @rodorgas td bem, não seja o caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso, o mais adequado seria utilizar caminhos virtuais como no exemplo abaixo. Assim mesmo que esteja acessando seus projetos via file system ou se criar uma hospedagem local para o site `DesenvolvimentoWeb`, irá manter a mesma funcionalidade.

E evite apontar o link apenas para um diretório se não houver um servidor para responder ao request, isso vai apresentar um comportamento em cada browser, OS e versão, dependendo inclusive em que diretório você está salvando seus arquivos. Sem um servidor não irá abrir o index ou default daquele diretório. Ou listar os arquivos no browser ou vai abrir o diretório no explorador do OS ou não vai fazer nada ou ainda, retornar um erro.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <title>Projetos</title>
 
</head>

<body>
   
    <ul>
        <li class="feito"><a href="../pm-proj001/index.html">Projeto 001</a></li>
        <li class="feito"><a href="../pm-proj002/index.html">Projeto 002</a></li>
        <li class="feito"><a href="../pm-proj003/index.html">Projeto 003</a></li>

    </ul>
    
</body>
</html>
```